# Species cartography with R

Tags: r, mapping, r-factor

I have a small data frame (see below) containing 2 species "Aganope" and "Brienope" (factor format) with its geographical coordinates (19 lines records for Aganope and 12 lines for Brienope). I want to make the map of this species and, for the first one, my code is:

```
library(dismo)
str(data)
data
data<-data[1:19,]
str(data)
data
acgeo <- subset(data, !is.na(EST) & !is.na(SOUTH))
dim(acgeo)
acgeo[1:19, c(1:3,1:3)]
# Placer tous les lieux de récolte de Aganope sur le fond de carte bioclimate 5
points(acgeo$EST, acgeo$SOUTH, col="red", pch=21, bg="black", cex=1)
```

In this code, I choose my species by the number of lines of the data frame (here species "Aganope" since line 1 to line 19). I will have very soon many more species in this data frame. 
My question is : Do you have a method for mapping this species by the factor's name (Aganope or Brienope) and NOT by numbering the line of the data frame?

Yours sincerely

Here is my data frame

```
Number  Species_name    Collector_name  East    South  
1   Aganope Antila_1186 49.8427778  -15.4327778  
2   Aganope Bar_2365    48.4166667  -17.5500000  
3   Aganope Bern_1760   50.2344444  -15.3352778  
4   Aganope Carl_43 49.7500000  -15.4833333  
5   Aganope Flore_1979  49.7666667  -15.5000000  
6   Aganope Milir_3654  49.7666667  -15.5000000  
7   Aganope Perret_2062 50.4333333  -15.1833333  
8   Aganope Raharim_21401   49.7166667  -16.4500000  
9   Aganope Ralim_109   50.0138889  -15.2869444  
10  Aganope Sciza_1351  49.9500000  -15.6000000  
11  Aganope Sciza_1354  50.0166667  -15.7833333  
12  Aganope Sciza_1370  49.7666667  -15.5000000  
13  Aganope Sciza_2016  49.7666667  -15.5000000  
14  Aganope Serfa_18305 49.8497222  -15.4194444  
15  Aganope Serfa_19221 49.3916667  -17.2833333  
16  Aganope Serfa_28814 49.8833333  -16.8833333  
17  Aganope Serfa_28847 49.8997222  -16.8983333  
18  Aganope Serfa_32138 48.9333333  -19.0333333  
19  Aganope Serfa_32245 48.9333333  -19.0333333  
20  Brienope    Dery_10119  47.1000000  -24.9833333  
21  Brienope    Dery_10210  46.9350000  -25.0486111  
22  Brienope    Dery_4230   46.9983333  -25.0397222  
23  Brienope    Dutz_544    47.0000000  -24.9500000  
24  Brienope    Dutz_756    47.1666667  -24.7833333  
25  Brienope    Rabetra_1835    46.8500000  -25.0666667  
26  Brienope    Rabetra_1892    47.0000000  -24.9500000  
27  Brienope    Rason_5 47.1569444  -24.8127778  
28  Brienope    Ratafika_748    46.9980556  -25.0405556  
29  Brienope    Scott_2473  46.9963889  -25.0416667  
30  Brienope    Serfa_21443 47.2000000  -24.5750000  
31  Brienope    Serfa_28332 46.9330556  -25.0494444
```

Comment: You didn't include a sample value for `data` here so your problem isn't [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Read that link for tips on sharing sample data so that we can run the same code as you. Why have you included `library(dismo)` here? You don't seem to be using any functions from that package. I'm guessing you might just want `acgeo[acgeo[,1]=="Aganope",]` assuming that the species is in the first column.

Comment: have you tried `newdata <- acgeo[acgeo$species == "Aganope",]`? that's similar to what @MrFlick suggested, but if `data` is something `gbif` produced (or a similar function), then you can just subset on the `species` column.

Comment: As an advance thank you for yours responses. I send in the previous message my data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Note that you cannot call points without calling a plot before. There're some other issues with the notation used in your code and the one in the table.

```
data <- read.csv() #Your raw data
subset<-data[data$Species_name == "Aganope",]
plot(subset$East, subset$South, col="red", pch=21, bg="black", cex=1)
```

Good luck!